# AS3 error #1009 on trying to move to next frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cs3

In my program I have a small arrow spinning around, this is the code im using

```
import flash.events.Event;

var spinSpeed:Number = 2;

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void{

myMovieClip.rotation += spinSpeed;

}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 



btnnext14.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(39);
}
```

It works fine and the arrow spins, but when I try and go to the next slide, I get an error #1009

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at pp2_fla::MainTimeline/onEnterFrame()[pp2_fla.MainTimeline::frame38:9]
```

Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely your issue:

On whatever frame the code you posted runs, you add an enter_frame listener.
You may not be aware that this enter_frame listener you created will keep running even after you change to frame 39.

Most likely on frame 39 your `myMovieClip` object doesn't exist anymore, so when your `onEnterFrame` runs from frame 39 it errors out.

To remedy this, remove the enter_frame listener before you move on to frame 39:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); 
    gotoAndStop(39);
}
```